# Trying to update the value of global variable in Shell Script

Tags: shell

```
myfunc3()
{
    echo $1
}

myfunc2()
{
    input=$(myfunc3 10)
    echo "someting that will be used later"
}

myfunc1() {
    var=$(myfunc2) #this does not update the value
    # myfunc2 This updates the value
}

input="$(myfunc3 1)"
echo "The new value is: $input"
myfunc1
echo "The new value is: $input"
```

I have 3 functions that are interrelated. I am trying to update the value of the `input` variable. I am able to do it when I simply call the function `myfunc2` but when I am trying to get the returned value like `var=$(myfunc2)` as I want to use it for further uses, then the value of the `input` variable is not updating.

I am very new to shell scripting and I'm not able to understand the reasoning behind it.

Is there any other way to return the value or calling the function?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `var=$(myfunc2)` runs `myfunc2` in a subshell, so the global variable `input` is only changed in that subshell.  The value is lost as soon as the subshell exits.

Comment: @WilliamPursell thank you for the explanation. How can I overcome this hurdle?

Comment: Refactor your code to avoid using the global. It's a bad idea to be manipulating globals in this way.